# Xamarin forms Fomated Label span visible only after binding is resolved

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a few labels with formatted text that contains a few spans like this

```
    <Label>
         <Label.FormattedText>
               <FormattedString>
                      <Span Text="Size: "/>
                      <Span FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Item.Size , Mode=OneWay}"/>
                      <Span FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Item.Unit, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               </FormattedString>
           </Label.FormattedText>
       </Label>
```

and it looks like this:  size: **32oz.**  I want that the word 'size:' should appear only when the context property is resolved from the database

Comment: You could use a converter instead

Comment: but I won't be able to format it

Comment: I can also do stringformat but i want a different format for each span

Comment: You want to hide the whole `Label` or just hide the text **Size** ?

Comment: either one will work

Comment: Let's say you want to hide the whole label here. Creating a Converter something like `ValueToVisibilityConverter` and bind it to the `IsVisible` property of the label. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter to hide the entire label. I'm assuming the `Item.Size` is a string, however in the converter, you can cast to the correct type. Here is a sample

```
 public class OzViewConverter : IValueConverter
        {

            #region IValueConverter implementation

            public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var test = value as string; //here you can change the cast, depending on type object you are Binding 
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))  
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

Then, in your page

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:OzViewConverter x:Key="OzViewConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

 <Label IsVisible="{Binding Item.Unit, Converter={StaticResource OzViewConverter}}">
         <Label.FormattedText>
               <FormattedString>
                      <Span Text="Size: "/>
                      <Span FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Item.Size , Mode=OneWay}"/>
                      <Span FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Item.Unit, Mode=OneWay}"/>
               </FormattedString>
           </Label.FormattedText>
       </Label>
```